# Android - Convert String to byte[]

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays

I want to convert the string of "icon" to byte array and than to convert it to Bitmap. The problem is the image in the emulator is not displaying. I suppose I'm not doing right but I  know why. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

This is my JSON Data :

```
{
    "project": [
        {
            "abbreviation": "abd",
            "customer": "customer1",
            "description": "description1",
            "icon": "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",
            "name": "projectname1",
            "plannedEndDate": "2012-05-25T00:00:00+01:00",
            "plannedStartDate": "2012-05-23T00:00:00+01:00",
            "projectStatus": {
                "name": "Opened"
            },
            "realEndDate": "2012-05-25T00:00:00+01:00",
            "realStartDate": "2012-05-23T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I did it like that but it's not working :

```
// convert String to byte[]
String stringToConvert = project.getIcon();
byte[] theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes();

// convert Byte[] to Bitmap
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(theByteArray,
        0, theByteArray.length);
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

holder.imageIcon.setMinimumHeight(dm.heightPixels);
holder.imageIcon.setMinimumWidth(dm.widthPixels);
holder.imageIcon.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the string `icon`  it seems you have converted your image to string by using **Base64**. So you have to convert it back to bytes using Base64 itself

```
// Receiving side
byte[] data = Base64.decode(iconString, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

To decode your **base64** `string` to `byte[]`:

```
byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decode(strBase64.getBytes());
```

To convert your `byte[]` to `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length)
```

Now use your `bitmap` with your images's **setImageBitmap** method to show the output. For example:

```
icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I have to do it like this It get en error when I did it like you said : byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decode(strBase64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

Answer (score 2):

Your icon is Base64 encoded, use [Base64 class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) to decode it.